Why is the reaction force at A upward? Shouldn't it be downard?

Textbook says reaction force at A is upward. In my mind I'm keep thinking it should go downward. Or is reaction force on y axis always upward?

Tip: SE policy is that you credit the authors of material referenced in your posts. Otherwise it's considered plagiarism. There's an [edit] link below your post. Welcome to E.SE.

the direction depends on whether C is hanging from A, or C supports A

This question is similar to: What's going on with internal forces and reaction forces?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Upper part is in tension and lower part in compression. Other way of thinking about it is to split the beam at $C$ and also split the load $P$ into $P_A$ acting on the top part and $P_B$ acting on the bottom part, after which you end up with 2 sets of opposite forces; $P_A$ and $R_A$ on the top and $P_B$ and $R_B$ on the bottom. If deflection of both parts at $C$ is the same, this situation is equivalent to the original example.
